# smtp error "550 Delivery not allowed to"

Tags: smtp, email-server

Our Moodle (course management website) has been configured with an email account that can send emails to the students. The created email address is working fine. I mean I can login to the mail server and check the inbox of this user (the moodle). Also, there is a plugin for testing the setting. The log shows that delivery is not allowed and I don't know which side is causing such a problem, either the mail server admin or some setting errors.

```
SERVER -> CLIENT: 235 Authentication successful
CLIENT -> SERVER: MAIL FROM:
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data was ""
SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "250 Sender accepted
                                  "
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "250 Sender accepted
                                  "
SERVER -> CLIENT: 250 Sender accepted
CLIENT -> SERVER: RCPT TO:
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data was ""
SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "550 Delivery not allowed to 
                                  "
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "550 Delivery not allowed to 
                                  "
SERVER -> CLIENT: 550 Delivery not allowed to 
SMTP ERROR: RCPT TO command failed: 550 Delivery not allowed to 
CLIENT -> SERVER: QUIT
```

Any feedback for that?

Comment: Alarm, monkeys with grenade here!!!

Answer (score 0):

Hire good admin and|or programmer, which will be able to see and to implement obvious for any real hostmaster thing - correct and RFC-compliant SMTP-session (consult with RFC 2821 or even with ol' good RFC 821, Chapter 3, "Example of the SMTP Procedure"). **Now it's terribly bad**

**Quote from "Example of the SMTP Procedure"**

```
    S: MAIL FROM:<Smith@Alpha.ARPA>
    R: 250 OK

    S: RCPT TO:<Jones@Beta.ARPA>
    R: 250 OK

    S: RCPT TO:<Green@Beta.ARPA>
    R: 550 No such user here

    S: RCPT TO:<Brown@Beta.ARPA>
    R: 250 OK

    S: DATA
    R: 354 Start mail input; end with <CRLF>.<CRLF>
    S: Blah blah blah...
    S: ...etc. etc. etc.
    S: <CRLF>.<CRLF>
    R: 250 OK
```

In plain English - `MAIL FROM` and `RCPT TO` **must to have** parameter, without at least 1 recipient ("forward-path" from RCPT TO) you will not step up to DATA stage